# How to avoid changing & to &amp; when display ajax response into div?

Tags: php

I got a php script(getit.php) that prints out some hyperlinks. i am calling that phpscript using ajax and display it in div. The problem is that all these hyperlink urls have `&amp;` instead of just having `&` **(when i view selection source in firefox**)!!If hyperlink urls have `&amp;` then it will not function correctly! However if i call the getit.php script directly the hyperlinks got `&` only.

How i can avoid `&` converted to `&amp;` when calling the php script using ajax ? my goal is to copy those hyperlinks and use them elsewhere but all the hyperlinks get `&amp` instead of just `&` . Is there a way to display the hyperlinks html source codes in to textbox instead of showing them in div and have only `&`? In another word how to append ajax response source code into textarea?

getit.php script :

```
echo "<a href=\"../test/doit.php?variable=".$result2.".net/";
echo ("&");
echo "id1=".$result."&id2=".$result3."&title=".$title_name."\">".$title_name."</a>";  
echo "<br>";
```

ajax call to getit.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addHit(str,str2) {

$.ajax(
{
      type: 'GET',
    url: './getit.php'+pagenumber,
    url: './getit.php?value='+str+'&title='+str2,

            success: function (good)
            {
              //handle success

                  //alert(good)
                 $('#myDiv').append(good)

            },
            failure: function (bad)
            {
               //handle any errors

                alert(bad)

            }



});

}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="addHit('http://www.somesite.com/value/12','Episode 12')" > episode 12 </a> <br />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="addHit('http://www.somesite.com/value/13','Episode 13')" > episode 13 </a> <br />


<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: I think `&amp;` in `href` attributes should be OK, the browser will translate them to `&` when you click on the link.

Comment: i found a way around it by using textarea a place for html response .But dont know how to append it ?    $("textarea[name='content']").html(good); how to append this response in textarea?

Comment: $("textarea[name='content']").html($("textarea[name='content']").html()+good);

Comment: You actually want `&amp;` instead of `&`.  This is the only way to get valid HTML.  I don't see anywhere in your script where you actually do that, so the browser is parsing your invalid HTML and being nice to you.  Always use `htmlspecialchars()` around variable data used in an HTML context.  May I also suggest `http_build_query()`?

Comment: Thanks guys .barmar can i place each response in separate line in textarea using this code you posted above ? $("textarea[name='content']").html($("textarea[name='content']").html()+good);  is working fine but i just want to go to nextline for each response!

Answer (score 1):

This will append to the HTML of a textarea:

```
var textarea = $("textarea[name='content']");
textarea.html(textarea.html()+good);
```